# WAS: Jython script to map module to servers after install

Tags: module, websphere, jython, wsadmin

We are using UrbanCode Deploy to install ear files to WAS. The install step works but afterwards mapping a particular resource to servers step fails.

As shown below, there are two modules in the ear file, using the same UCD step, the first module mapping went through but the 2nd failed. I want to write my own script to do this failed mapping. What's the command to do this mapping for the 2nd module?

```
WMOServicesWeb  WMOServicesWeb.war,WEB-INF/web.xml  Web Module  WebSphere:cell=uauswad03Cell,node=uauswad03Node,server=ConnectAppSvr2
WebSphere:cell=uauswad03Cell,node=uauswad03IHS,server=webserver

ECIResourceAdapter  ResourceAdapter6022.rar,META-INF/ra.xml Connector Module    WebSphere:cell=uauswad03Cell,node=uauswad03Node,server=ConnectAppSvr2
WebSphere:cell=uauswad03Cell,node=uauswad03IHS,server=webserver
```

Comment: You could do an update in the admin console following [these](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/crun_app_upgrade.html) instructions (choose the *Single module* update), and then use the [command assist](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0812_rhodes/0812_rhodes.html) function of the admin console to capture the relevant wsadmin command.  You might still need to parameterize some piece of this, but this should be fairly simple at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Similar scenario is explained in detail here : [Deploy to Websphere cluster using WAS - Deploy plugin](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/239807/deploy-to-websphere-cluster-using-was-deploy-plugi/)

From the above link

```
Use the following one (substitute module names with .*):

-MapModulesToServers [[ .* .* WebSphere:cell=IBM277-
R90FKAU9Cell01,cluster=Cluster1+WebSphere:cell=IBM 277-
R90FKAU9Cell01,node=IBM277-R90FKAU9Node01,server=webserver1 ]

This will map all EAR modules to the same targets.
```